# MySQL Transactions during DB switching

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I am working with MySQL transactions and have a question.

Say I have started a transaction on a database A using:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
```

where $mysqli is handle to my database A and I do some queries.

Now without reconnecting and commiting, I select another DB Database B using:

```
$mysqli->select_db("B");
```

Now, will the transactions which I started on database A still be effective even after switching the DB?

I want the transactions to commit only after I give `$mysql->commit()` and not when switching DBs.

And if there are any errors, will it rollback in DB A as well as DB B if the transactions were started with handle as DB A?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to switch db? Just reference tables and fields with dbname.table or dbname.tablename.fieldname.

Comment: From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html, I'd say you should be safe. The transaction should survive the `USE <db>` statement.

Comment: @HannoBinder: Useful Info. I guess I would be safe though I am not entirely sure. Thanks

Comment: @Shadow: You are right but the fact is that I have written thousands of queries already and dont want to change them to that way now. Painful job. (Making a social networking website. So need this for sure)

Comment: @HannoBinder: are you aware if it would rollback changes in DB A when there is a problem in DB B ?

Comment: The easier way than switching databases is most times to use more than one database handle and associate them with the databases.

Comment: @vignesh If the transaction is not implicitly committed in between, a rollback will rollback everything to the start of the transaction.

Comment: @syck: If I use multiple handles, how will I get the transactions to rollback changes made to DB A when an error occurs in DB B? Cause I have to supply handles to transactions.

Comment: @HannoBinder: Thank you. Will put it to use then.

Comment: @vignesh Thats why I said "most times". But you still can start transactions simultaneously on both handles and do roll back on both if you need to.